# How to fold the commented code in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Vscode, How to fold the commented/inactived code region? 
Lua Code
[lua code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90x9T.png)
or cpp Code
[cpp code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9qmH.png)

They are unabled to fold the code which is commented or inactived. such as in visual studio
[folded code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dva4N.png)

Answer (score 1):

Its a known bug.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/407

An alternative could be to encapsulate your unwanted code into a region.

```
#region Accessors
// Commented code
#endregion
```

The alternative commenting mechanism

```
/*  

// More code
// commented code youre not interested in

*/
```

Here is an extension that has been made which attempts to solve the issue

https://github.com/reapler/vscode-cfold

Comment: need It to add `#region Accessors` and `#region Accessors`every time when i comment the codes?

Comment: @SambeauWang Added another one for you, but /* could be used also. It is a known bug. I will list an extension found at the bottom of the form.

Comment: `/*` is work in cpp code. Which approach can be used in commented code in vscode( different language)?

Comment: Thank you for help very much! Waiting for the fix.

Comment: @SambeauWang If this is the correct answer feel free to mark it so, enables others to find the solution too :)